# Calculate Hamming distance between strings of variable length in Matlab

Tags: string, matlab, hamming-distance, variable-length

I would like to calculate the Hamming distance between two strings of variable length in Matlab. For fixed length strings the following syntax solves my problem:

```
str1 = 'abcde';
str2 = 'abedc';

sum(str1 ~= str2)

ans = 2
```

How can I do this efficiently for variable length strings?

Thank you!

EDIT: Because this is a legitimate question: For every character one string is longer then the other, the Hamming distance should be incremented. So for example for

```
str1 = 'abcdef';
str2 = 'abc';
```

The answer should be 3.

Comment: Your code works for variable length strings. Or do you mean one string can be longer than the other? If so, how do you define Hamming distance for that case?

Comment: Good question, I'll add an explanation to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

```
str1 = 'abcdef';
str2 = 'abc';
clear t
t(1,:) = str1+1; % +1 to make sure there are no zeros
t(2,1:numel(str2)) = str2+1; % if needed, this right-pads with zero or causes t to grow
result = sum(t(1,:)~=t(2,:));
```

Comment: Thank you, that works! I wasn't aware that matrices can grow with a simple syntax like this!

Answer (score 1):

although @LuisMendo answer works for the given example (which might be good enough for you) it will not work for this one:

```
str1 = 'abcdef';
str2 = 'bcd';
clear t
t(1,:) = str1+1; % +1 to make sure there are no zeros
t(2,1:numel(str2)) = str2+1; % if needed, this right-pads with zero or causes t to grow
result = sum(t(1,:)~=t(2,:)) % result = 6
```

to make sure that even if the shorter string appears in the middle of the longer one you should check all options. one way to do that is:

```
str1 = 'bcd';
str2 = 'abcdef';
len1 = length(str1);
len2 = length(str2);
n = len2 - len1;
str1rep_temp = repmat(str1,[1,n+1]);
str1rep = -ones(n+1,len2);
str1rows = repmat(1:n+1,[len1,1]);
str1cols = bsxfun(@plus,(1:len1)',0:n);
str1idxs = sub2ind(size(str1rep),str1rows(:),str1cols(:));
str1rep(str1idxs) = str1rep_temp;
str2rep = double(repmat(str2,[n+1, 1]));
res = min(sum(str1rep ~= str2rep,2)); % res = 3
```

Comment: Ok, I didn't even think of doing it like this, but this is an interesting approach anyways. Maybe I will try that later on, thank you!